# What other tips to improve my cordova-based app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webview

I currently develop an hybrid app based on Cordova. My main target is Android devices with at least 2.3 support.

I face performance issues, particularly scrolling which is not really smooth and more generally navigation inside app. So I implemented several tips to increase my app speed such as:

- Hardware acceleration
- Use the fastest scroller I found ([FTScroller](https://github.com/ftlabs/ftscroller))
- Use [hogan.js](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js) for view rendering with pre-compiled template

I tried Famousjs and CocoonJS but it didn't help. I look to crosswalk-cordova, but it increase the size of the app by 15-20mb and I have to keep the size as light as possible.

The app performs pretty good on powerful devices such as my Nexus 5, but it become slow on older/less powerful devices.
So what other tips could I use to increase the speed of my app ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"but it become slow on older/less powerful devices", does this issue happens when you are using crosswalk?

I guess on older/less powerful devices, if the performance drops dramatically,  it maybe related the the GPU blacklist, Which means on some old devices GPU are blacklisted.  To resolve this issue, you can pass '--ignore-gpu-blaclist' option,

see: https://crosswalk-project.org/#wiki/Use-Chromium-command-lines-in-your-apps-on-Android

Comment: Not when I'm using crosswalk because I don't use it. Its support is too much limited.

Comment: Sorry to hear that... could you be more specific on which support you need when using crosswalk?  we'll try improve it as much as we can:)

Comment: I would like Crosswalk support Android 2.3+ and other platforms such as iOS, Windows Phone.